# Mathematical principles and theorems - what is the difference?

Tags: terminology

For me, intuitively, a mathematical principle is simply *an influential theorem*.

Still, I am not clear on how and who decides (or decided) if a theorem/statement is a mathematical principle.

Can you clarify this to me?

NOTE: Wikipedia lists [around 40 mathematical principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Mathematical_principles), in various fields, and of various significance. For example:

- [Cavalieri's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle)
- [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)
- [Homotopy principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_principle)
- [Reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle)
- [Littlewood's three principles of real analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood%27s_three_principles_of_real_analysis)

Comment: Zorn's *lemma*, the well-ordering *principle*, the *axiom* of choice. Naming of things is historically contingent, there's no logic to it.

Comment: I recommend reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem#Terminology It mentions common uses of the terms lemma, axiom, principle, theorem, corollary, etc and as user4894 mentioned above me the differences between the terms is largely arbitrary with little to no difference between the uses.